# How to get data-attrribute of a button and display that page?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the **data-attribute** of the **clicked buttons** and **display page** according to that?

It says: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined when I click on a button,hovewer it consols it´s value fine. Isn´t this the way you set the value of data attribute to a variable e.g

```
aTargetPage = this.getAttribute('data-ShowPage');
```

Example:

```js
btnViewPage = document.querySelectorAll(".btnViewPage");
for (i = 0; i < btnViewPage.length; i++) {
  btnViewPage[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    aPages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
    aTargetPage = this.getAttribute('data-ShowPage');
    console.log(aTargetPage);
    for (j = 0; j < aPages.lenght; j++) {
      aPages[j].style.display = "none";
      aTargetPage.style.display = "flex";
      console.log(aTargetPage);

    }
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="btnViewPage" data-showPage="pageSaveShop" type="button">SAVE SHOP</button>
<button class="btnViewPage" data-showPage="pageViewShopsLocation" type="button">VIEW SHOPS LOCATION</button>
<div id="pageSaveShop" class="page">
  <div id="lblSaveShop">
    <h1>SAVE SHOPS</h1>
    <form id="frmSaveShop" method="post">
      <input id=txtShopName name="txtShopName" type "text">
      <input id=txtShopPhoneNumber name="txtShopPhoneNumber" type="number">
      <input id=txtShopLatitude name="txtShopLatitude" type="hidden">
      <input id=txtShopLongtitude name="txtShopLongtitude" type="hidden">
      <div id="mapSaveShopLocation"></div>
      <button id="btnSaveShop" type="button">SAVE SHOP</button>
    </form>
    <h3 id="lblSaveShopErrorMessage"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pageViewShopsDetails" class="page">
  <div id="lblShopList">

  </div>
</div>
<div id="pageUpdateShop" class="page">
  <div id="lblUpdateShop">
    <h1>UPDATE SHOPS</h1>
    <form id="frmUpdateShop" method="post">
      <input id=txtUpdateShopName name="txtUpdateShopName" type "text">
      <input id=txtUpdateShopPhoneNumber name="txtUpdateShopPhoneNumber" type="number">
      <input id=txtUpdateShopLatitude name="txtUpdateShopLatitude" type="hidden">
      <input id=txtUpdateShopLongtitude name="txtUpdateShopLongtitude" type="hidden">
      <div id="mapUpdateShopLocation"></div>
      <button id="btnUpdateShop" type="button">UPDATE SHOP</button>
    </form>
    <h3 id="lblUpdateShopErrorMessage"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pageViewShopsLocation" class="page">
  <div id="lblViewShopsLocation">
    <h1>SHOPS ON MAP</h1>
    <div id="mapViewShopLocation"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: attribute names should be lowercase - but yes, if the attribute is on btnViewPage then `this.getAttribute("attributename")` is the way to get it - but that is only a guess when you do not show the relevant HTML

Comment: just updated with the HTML.

Comment: aTargetPage is a string, you want `document.getElementById(aTargetPage) `or `document.querySelector("#"+aTargetPage)` - bout you also should rename `data-showPage` to `data-showpage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you want to assign style to the value of the data-showPage attribute (which is string). You probably want something like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < aPages.length; j++) {
  aPages[j].style.display = "none";
} // this will hide all
var page = document.querySelector("#" + aTargetPage) // this will find the right page
if (page) {
  page.style.display = 'flex'; // this will show it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

also a spelling mistake:

for (j = 0; j < aPages.lenght; j++) { => lenght should be length

Answer (score 0):

you can access dataset object and get the property by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are converted to camelCase).

```
aTargetPage = this.dataset.ShowPage; //as reviewing your HTML seems you are using "data-showPage" attribute rather than "data-ShowPage" and for that you have to access the dataset as

aTargetPage = this.dataset.showPage; // i checked your html this should work for your case
```